# Devise-token-auth with axios bug

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, devise, axios

I'm using axios with a restful api that uses devise-token-auth and is set to change headers on each request with batch request buffer throttle of 5 seconds. I can sign in and make multiple good calls (that are using the same token if less than 5 seconds) and receives a new token and uses it in the next call. My problem is that it will either revert to an old token that i am not getting in response. Or will just fail on a good token. Any advice?

[Call](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ujwXL.png)

[Axios Client](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xlzD1.png)

Comment: Please include relevant code samples and/or logs so that we can get a better idea of what is going on.

Comment: In your `Axios Client`, in `_cycleAccessToken` method you are storing the token as `localStorage.setItem('auth', JSON.stringify({auth: headers.auth}))` It should be **`localStorage.setItem('auth', JSON.stringify({auth: headers}))`**

Comment: That's how I initially had it. When it is just headers and not headers.auth, it will only work for one call because the whole JSON object get's wrapped in another auth object.

Comment: That part works the way i would expect it to because it is always replacing just the access-token. The problem is that every once in a while it will change the token (in the call photo) to a token that i'm not receiving from the response